# Bios does not detect the usb key to boot it

Tags: mount, windows, bootable

I want to create a MS-Windows bootable usb using linux (I'm using rpi4 to do it).
I formatted the usb mass-storage-device as follow:

```
df -h 
sudo umount /dev/sda1
udo mkfs.ntfs  /dev/sda1
```

Then I used `Woeusb` to create a bootable key.
The problem is, when I open the Bios menu the usb key is not mentioned in the list of options.

Is there any other solution to create an efficient MS-Windows usb bootable using linux commands or another tools that I can use on rpi4?

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 28.7 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors
Disk model: Ultra Fit       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8ce29cf2

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           8192 60087295 60079104 28.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       60087296 60088319     1024  512K  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
```

[image: Boot 1]

Boot folder:

[image: boot2]

Comment: I added to my question

Comment: Try setting the boot flag for your second partition. fdisk /dev/sda -> a -> 2 -> w -> q

Comment: `Disk /dev/sda: 28.7 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors
Disk model: Ultra Fit       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8ce29cf2

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           8192 60087295 60079104 28.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *    60087296 60088319     1024  512K  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
`

Comment: But still the same issue with the bios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many solutions and different tools to create a bootable usb key to reinstall windows on my laptop. I finally discovered a great and amazing article [Creating a Bootable Windows 10 UEFI USB Drive Using Linux](https://techbit.ca/2019/02/creating-a-bootable-windows-10-uefi-usb-drive-using-linux/) which resolved the issue and I can create a bootable key sucessfully.